# mysql connector not downloading

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, mysql-connector

pip._vendor.pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'pip==20.1.1' distribution was not found and is required by the application

-this is the error message that I keep getting.I have the latest version of pip and I have no idea why its not being found when I have pip version 20 installed.

Comment: The error is vague. Provide more details: OS, IDE, and console errors. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

after uninstalling python and reinstalling using brew the problem began to solve itself.